# Dealing with Swift 5 Exclusivity Enforcement when using Combine

Tags: swift, combine

Swift 5, the "Exclusive Access to Memory" enforcement is now on by default for release builds as mentioned in this Swift.org blog post:

[Swift 5 Exclusivity Enforcement](https://swift.org/blog/swift-5-exclusivity/)

I understand the reasoning behind this feature, but with the new `Combine` framework I feel as if some very normal design patterns are now going to break and I'm curious how best to work around them.

With `Combine` it's natural for parts of your code to react to changes in a model such that they might need to read from the very property that the model has just changed. But they can no longer do that because it will trigger a memory exception as you attempt to read a value that is currently being set.

Consider the following example:

```
struct PasswordProposal {
  let passwordPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("1234")
  let confirmPasswordPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("1234")

  var password:String {
    get { passwordPublisher.value }
    set { passwordPublisher.value = newValue }
  }

  var confirmPassword:String {
    get { confirmPasswordPublisher.value }
    set { confirmPasswordPublisher.value = newValue }
  }

  var isPasswordValid:Bool {
    password == confirmPassword && !password.isEmpty
  }
}

class Coordinator {
  var proposal:PasswordProposal
  var subscription:Cancellable?

  init() {
    self.proposal = PasswordProposal()
    self.subscription = self.proposal.passwordPublisher.sink { [weak self] _ in
      print(self?.proposal.isPasswordValid ?? "")
    }
  }

  // Simulate changing the password to trigger the publisher.
  func changePassword() {
    proposal.password = "7890"
  }
}

// --------------------------------

var vc = Coordinator()
vc.changePassword()
```

As soon as `changePassword()` is called, the mutual exclusivity enforcement will throw an exception because the property `password` will attempt to be read from while it's currently being written to.

Note that if you change this example to use a separate backing storage property instead of the `CurrentValueSubject` it causes the same exception.

However, if you change `PasswordProposal` from being a `struct` to a `class`, then the exception is no longer thrown.

When I consider how I might use `Combine` in an existing codebase, as well as in `SwiftUI`, I see this type of pattern coming up in a lot of places. In the old delegate model, it's quite common for a delegate to query the sending object from within a delegate callback. In Swift 5, I now have to be very careful that none of those callbacks potentially read from the property that initiated the notification.

Have others come across this and, if so, how have you addressed it? Apple has routinely suggested that we should be using `structs` where it makes sense but perhaps an object that has published properties is one of those areas where it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

The `password` property is not the problem. It's actually the `proposal` property. If you add a `didSet` property observer to `proposal`, you'll see it's getting reset when you set `password`, then you access `self?.proposal` from within your sink while it's being mutated.

I doubt this is the behavior that you want, so it seems to me like the correct solution is to make `PasswordProposal` a class.

Comment: The problem with `didSet` is that it's not available on property wrappers since the `value` property is computed. In a more real-world example, `proposal` is a wrapped property that exposes a `Publisher` for interested parties. Ideally, the `Publisher` would fire in a `didSet`, but that's not possible. So it has to fire in the `set` which can then easily trigger the exclusivity exception. (You can put a `didSet` observer on the non-synthesized property, but then you have to do that for each property, which is nowhere near as convenient as defining it in a reusable property wrapper.)

Comment: I'm not suggesting `didSet` as part of the solution, just as proof of my point, which is that `proposal` is being reset every time you set `password`. My solution is to make `PasswordProposal` a class.

Comment: In this simple example, sure. I was just trying to keep the sample code short. In "real life", I have a `class` that manages things like settings, preferences, configuration options, etc, that has tons of properties. Most of the properties are primitives but some are currently structs. Indeed, converting them to `classes` solves the problem, as noted above, but I *feel* that goes against some of Apple's latest recommendations. When I think of all of the different areas I'd love to use `Combine` for property observation, most of those places use `structs`.